# TypeError: join() argument must be str or bytes, not 'TextIOWrapper

Tags: scikit-learn

I have features and a target variable which I am wanting to generate a Decision Tree. However, the code is throwing an error. Since the 'out file' did not generate an error, I figured there wouldn't be an error for the 'Source.from_file' either, but there is one.

```
import os
from graphviz import Source
from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz
f = open("C:/Users/julia/Desktop/iris_tree.dot", 'w')
export_graphviz(
        tree_clf,
        out_file=f,
        feature_names=sample2[0:2],
        class_names=sample2[5],
        rounded=True,
        filled=True
    )
Source.from_file(f)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the [docs](https://graphviz.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=Source#graphviz.Source.from_file), `from_file` accepts a string path, not a file object:

> filename – Filename for loading/saving the source.

Just pass the path in:

```
import os
from graphviz import Source
from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz
path = "C:/Users/julia/Desktop/iris_tree.dot"
f = open(path, 'w')
export_graphviz(
        tree_clf,
        out_file=f,
        feature_names=sample2[0:2],
        class_names=sample2[5],
        rounded=True,
        filled=True
    )
Source.from_file(path)
```